# Powershell. Convert an array of items with one property to an array of strings

Tags: arrays, powershell

Often we use a Powershell command to get an array of objects, and we only want one property in each object (such as the name). Here's an example:

```
$OUs = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Servers,DC=mycompany,DC=com | Select-Object Name
```

The example above is *not* a list of strings. It's a list of custom object with the property names. It cannot be used for string comparisons.

```
$OUs

Name
----
OU1 
OU2
OU3
```

```
"OU1" -in $OUs
$OUs -contains "OU1"
#output is false, false

$OUStringList = "OU1","OU2","OU3"
"OU1" -in $OUStringList
$OUStringList -contains "OU1"
#output is true, true
```

Is use this clunky method to convert an array with one property to list of strings:

```
$OUStringList = @()
$OUs.foreach({$OUStringList+=$o.name})
$OUStringList -contains "OU1"
#output is $true
```

This works, but I'd like to avoid the extra lines of code, and the placeholder variables. Is there are better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `-ExpandProperty` argument:

```
$OUs = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Servers,DC=mycompany,DC=com" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

Or you can eschew piping to `Select-Object` at all and drop the `.Name` property [directly in the pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration?view=powershell-7.2):

```
$OUs = (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Servers,DC=mycompany,DC=com").Name
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to modify your code. Just use '$OUs.Name' to get strings.

E. g.:

```
$a=Get-Service
$a.DisplayName
```

Produces:

Application Layer Gateway Service

Application Host Helper Service

Application Identity

...